# How to update loaded configuration with newer version from db/cache intervally in aspnet core?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-identity

Currently, I am registering the service accessing key in `appsettings.json` like this:

```json
    // settings for allowing access from other services
    "AuthSetting": {
      "CookieAuthSetting": {
          "KeyForAccessingFromServiceZ": {
                 "ServiceName": "ServiceZ",
                 "DeveloperName": "dev1",
             },
      "IPAuthSetting": {
                  "IPWhiteList": ['aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa', 'bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb'],
                  "IPBlackList": ['ccc.ccc.ccc.ccc']
             }
      }
    },
   // key  for access to other service
   Neighbors: {
     "ServiceY": "KeyforAccessToY"
   }
```

and map the AuthSetting to Configuration in `startup.cs` like this:

```cs
            services.Configure<AuthSetting>(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(AuthSetting)));
            services.Configure<Neighbors>(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(Neighbors)));
```

for convenience， I want to store the auth info to centralization db/cache, so it will be easy to add an auth entry for new service or block access from some host dynamically

How can I achieve the following target:

- internally refresh the auth settings from db/cache/rpc
- load authsettings in local `appsettings.json` first for faster application start speed, and db/cache fail tolerant
- merge db/cache/rpc auth settings with local json setting file, when conflict, use auth settings from db/cache/rpc

Comment: in my humble opinion, I don't know why we need to merge settings stored in the db/cache to  the json setting file because we already have the data in the db and cache... could you pls explain more about your requirement?

Comment: @TinyWang the auth setting may changes, for example , add/remove access key, add/remove whitelist ip

Comment: yes... and we have them stored and updated in the db, we could get the latest data from db as well, and we don't need the settings content if not necessary....